# Copying Rows based on Cell Values and then adding subtotals

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am fairly new to vba. Before I decided to post this question, I did some research and found a similar solution, but was unable to successfully implement the code. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/715128-visual-basic-applications-copy-paste-entire-row-second-sheet-based-cell-value.html

I am on Microsoft Excel 2010 and windows 7. Basically, I am using an outside software to generate raw data into a blank workbook sheet called "Data." I would like to copy the data from sheet "Data" and present it in a sheet called "Summary." (I would like to add subtotals):

Using SQL server, I am bringing in column A as either "1" or "2." The rows that have value "1" would be placed starting on row 6, column C of sheet "Summary." The rows that have value "2" would start two rows after the first data set subtotals with the column titles. I would also like to exclude column A from the "Summary" Sheet. I have also included the code I started working on. I understand that the code I inserted is wrong, which is why I am posting this question:

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, r As Long

lr = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For r = lr To 2 Step -1
  If Range("A" & r).Value = "1" Then
    Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
    lr2 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  End If
  If Range("A" & r).Value = "2" Then
    Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
    lr3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  End If
  Range("A1").Select
Next r

End Sub
```

Am I on the right track? Can someone please help?

Comment: `I understand that the code I inserted is wrong,`  What's wrong with it?  Does it run?  if so, what is it doing that you aren't expecting?  If not, where is Excel throwing an error, and what is the error it is throwing?

Comment: I'm not receiving an error and none of the data from the "Data" sheet is being inserted into the "Summary" tab. I also was wondering if you could provide some help on adding subtotals to the two result sets i mentioned above. Please be aware that in my code I have specified the right "Summary" Tab - Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & lr2 + 1) and lr2 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: The code looks alright.  Instead of using the find last row lines each time you could just do lr2=lr2+1 since you are always copying 1 row.  Is the data sheet selected when you are doing it? Have you tried stepping through the code to see what it is actually doing?  Add watches to make sure it is actually stepping through the lines like you expect.  To exclude column A the easiest thing would be to delete the column at the end.

Comment: Well it's not only one row I'm copying. Column A might have 4 values of "1" so I would be copying 4 rows. So would that be right? Also, how can I add subtotals to these two result sets?

Comment: It looks like you have your answer already but a clarification on copying one row.  Each time through the loop you only copy one row.  lr=1 copy a row lr is now equal to 2, copy a row lr is now 3.  so instead of looking up the last row you can just add one.

Comment: FYI it's considered bad form to add to your question.  If you want to solve additional problems you should ask additional questions in separate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or .. a different approach
Sort the data first and autosense the last column with slightly shorter code

```
Sub CopyDatawithSort()

Dim sdRow As Long, sdCol As Long
Dim ssRow As Long, ssCol As Long

'data start r/c
sdRow = 2
sdCol = 1
'summary data start r/c
ssRow = 6
ssCol = 1

'last data row and column
ldrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ldCol = Sheets("Data").Cells(sdRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'sort data in order using column sdcol
Sheets("Data").Activate
    Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(sdRow, sdCol), Cells(ldrow, ldCol)).Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Columns(sdCol), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

'summary sheet column headers
    For r = 1 To ldCol
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(ssRow - 1, r).Value = "Col" & r
    Next r

'copy data
    Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(sdRow, sdCol), Cells(ldrow, ldCol)).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Cells(ssRow, ssCol)

'subtotals
    Sheets("Summary").Activate
    Sheets("Summary").Cells(ssRow, ssCol).Select
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=ssCol, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

'clear Col 1
    Sheets("Summary").Columns(ssCol).ClearContents

End Sub
```

EDIT TO MEET ADDITIONAL Q

I'm not sure that you can remove the Grand Total using the Excel SubTotal function so you will need to remove it using code.  Try the following:

```
Dim lsRow As Long
Dim gt As Range
```

and place the following code snippet before the 'clear Col 1 line

```
'remove grandtotal
    lsRow = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set gt = Range(Cells(ssRow, ssCol), Cells(lsRow, ssCol)).Find(After:=Cells(ssRow, ssCol), What:="Grand Total", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows)
    gt.EntireRow.Clear
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks; however, i am getting a final "Grand Total" after the two Subtotals which is essentially summing up all the rows leading up to the column headers. Do you know how to remove this last grand total?

Comment: My pleasure, hope it takes you forward.  Thanks for marking as Answer.

Comment: by the way, is there a way to hide the outlining 3 level buttons on the side after you subtotal? I'm getting a number of different answers on the web

Comment: nvm got it! ActiveWindow.DisplayOutline = False

Answer (score 1):

Is your data sheet selected/activated when the macro runs?  If not, then whatever sheet is active will be the sheet the data is being copied from.  This line:

```
Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
```

... copies the row "r" from the active sheet.  If you have "Summary" active so you can watch the magic happen then you are copying from "Summary" to "Summary"

So, either activate the "Data" sheet:

```
Sheets("Data").Activate
```

Or explicitly specify the sheet before the row:

```
Sheets("Data").Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
```

Edit:

In order to add a summary row for groupings by your column A you need to evaluate column A each loop to see if the next value is the same as the current one.  If the next value is not the same then you need to insert a summary line.  This also requires that you have a counter so you know how many rows must be summarized.

So, you need to include a line that counts the rows to group.  So this:

```
If Range("A" & r).Value = "1" Then
  rowCount = rowCount + 1
  Sheets("Data").Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
  lr2 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End If
```

And have a conditional statement inserts the summary line when the "group" is done:

```
If Range("A" & r).Value <> Range("A" & r - 1).Value Then
  'Do a bunch of stuff
End If
```

The "Do a bunch of stuff" depends on what you want to do.  Maybe in column A you do nothing, column B you sum, column C you average.  It depends on your preferences.  For example, though:

```
Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & r).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & rowCount & "]C:R[-1]C)"
```

This can get very elaborate and is made more complicated by the fact that you are adding rows in one sheet, but not the other.  I recommend that you play with this and if you need further help, pose a new question.  Multi-part questions become messy to interpret. and there are many, many ways to approach your question.

Comment: That worked. Would you know how to grab subtotals from both these two result sets? So lets say for example: There's 3 cells in Column A with Value "1" - which would give us 3 rows of data. Then There's 5 cells in Column A with Value "2" - which would give us 5 rows of data. I would like to add a subtotal 1 row after the first result set of Value "1" and then a subtotal 1 row after the second result set of Value "2." I would be summing the totals in column H. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to try and address this modification / extension of the initial question.  For now, please mark my answer as correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
I don't think you can have gaps between your data sets to implement Excel subtotals and you will also need column headings.  You can manually insert blank rows if you wish.
I have defined a row as noCols.  To me, no point in copying over 16,000 cols if you are only using a few?
It is a good idea to structure your variables to give you a bit more flexibility in formatting once you get going (and if I have misread your spec!).
I'll leave it to you to figure how to get whichever summary/total you require in col H from the output you have!
I have used some additional VBA statements which you can research yourself to take you forward.

```
Sub CopyData()


Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long, lr3 As Long
Dim oneStartRow As Long
Dim startCol As Long
Dim noCols As Long
Dim rc As Long


oneStartRow = 6
startCol = 1
noCols = 33
rc = 0

lr = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'headings
    For r = 1 To noCols
        Sheets("Summary").Cells(oneStartRow - 1, r).Value = "Col" & r
    Next r

'dataset 1     
    For r = 2 To lr
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(r, 1).Value = "1" Then
            Sheets("Data").Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, noCols).Copy
            Sheets("Summary").Cells(oneStartRow + rc, startCol).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            rc = rc + 1
        End If
    Next r

    lr3 = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    rc = 0

'dataset 2
    For r = 2 To lr
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(r, 1).Value = "2" Then
            Sheets("Data").Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, noCols).Copy
            Sheets("Summary").Cells(lr3 + rc, startCol).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            rc = rc + 1
        End If
    Next r

'subtotals        
    Sheets("Summary").Cells(8, 1).Select  'Anywhere in data to be grouped
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  'Array = Col no's to be summed

'clear col A
    Sheets("Summary").Columns(1).ClearContents 

End Sub
```